# jQuery Mobile - using AJAX within Form to inject html Before Submission

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

I have an existing jQueryMobile site that's working well. I now need to modify one of the HTML forms to use AJAX to update the page with some content that will be retrieved via a PHP script.

I've done this in the past with non jQueryMobile sites and would typically add a Javascript to the head section and add this attribute to the form element (an input text field in this particular case):

```
onchange="updateFormContent(this.value)"
```

The actual script would be like this:

```
function updateFormContent(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","nameSearch.php?name="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with my HTML Form on my jQueryMobile site and getting stuck. Here's a simple example of my HTML form:

http://jsfiddle.net/4zjSx/

When the user enters something in the Name field I would like to trigger the "nameSearch.php?name=" php page which searches the database for any matching names and displays the results on the same page, updating a DIV in the process.

Appreciate any tips to point me in the right direction or any working examples of a jQueryMobile form page that does something similar.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp

Think you are looking for this.